# How to send a conditional email depending on a google form answer on google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have just set up a google form that automatically populates a Google Sheet. I'm trying to set up an automatic email to notify a specific contact everytime someone submits a form and marks their test as positive. If they submit a negative test, I don't want it to send anything.

I've written the following with the following trigger:
Select event source - From Spreadsheet
Select event type - On from Submission

I've linked the formula to another Sheet for the script contacts. I managed to get it to send an email, however, it was previously sending an email even if a negative test was submitted. Because of this, I added another 'If' for a negative display but now it wont send anything at all.

Can anyone help? This is my first time coding any feel like I have hit a roadblock.

Formula:

```
function positiveemailsubmission()
{
    var positiverange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LFT Submissions").getRange("G2:G50000")
    var positivevalue = positiverange.getDisplayValue("Positive");
    {
      if (positivevalue.getDisplayValue() === "Positive")
      {
        var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Script info").getRange("B2");
        var emailAddress = emailRange.getDisplayValue();
        var message = 'A positive LFT test has been submitted. Please see the form for more information (WWW.DOCUMENTLINK.CO.UK)';
        var subject = 'Positive LFT Submission ';
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
      if (positivevalue.getDisplayValue() === "Negative") 
      {

      }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: At the very least there should be brakets `()` at the end of the method: `positivevalue.getDisplayValue()` Perhaps this will be enough.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, i've added the () to the value and it's now sending the email again, but its doing it for every submission, even if negative

Comment: Well... let's look on it closer then. Look, `positiverange` is a range of 50 thousands cells. `var positivevalue = positiverange.getDisplayValue("Positive")` it doesn't make sense (you're trying to get one value from thousands cells). It looks like you need just the very last row from the range. Am I right? And I think you dont even need to read the sheet. Likely you can get the value 'Positive' direct from the event object 'e' of the trigger: `onFormSubmit(e)`

Comment: Here is the example how you can send an email every time a form is submitted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518898/get-google-forms-responses-in-an-email-message/ Here is the example how you can get info from an event object `e`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132539/how-to-get-new-response-from-a-google-form-to-different-folders-based-on-the-for

Comment: As a quick fix (not sure if will work, though) you can try to change the line: `var positiverange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LFT Submissions").getRange("G2:G50000");` to `var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LFT Submissions"); var  positiverange = sh.getRange("G" + sh.getLastRow());` It will get you the last cell of column G.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide a proper response to the question, I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the solution is in the comments section.

Like @Yuri Khristich said, `positiverange` was a range of a lot of rows `"G2:G50000"`, in this case what you need is the value of the last row (last submit from Form) to determine if that specific answer was "Positive" or "Negative".

I tested your script with the changes mentioned in the comments and it worked.

```
function positiveemailsubmission()
{
    var positiverange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LFT Submissions");
    var  positivevalue = positiverange.getRange("G" + positiverange.getLastRow());
    {
      if (positivevalue.getDisplayValue() === "Positive")
      {
        var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Script info").getRange("B2");
        var emailAddress = emailRange.getDisplayValue();
        var message = 'A positive LFT test has been submitted. Please see the form for more information (WWW.DOCUMENTLINK.CO.UK)';
        var subject = 'Positive LFT Submission ';
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
      if (positivevalue.getDisplayValue() === "Negative") 
      {

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have now changed the formula and the submission portal is working perfectly. Thank you